# How to tag a project in cvs and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tags, cvs, project

I want to tag a release, but I don't see any option for it as below. I am using from eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `CVS Repositories` view (Window > Show View > Other > CVS Repositories). You should see your project location in this view. Navigate to you project and right clickt on it. You should then see the command `Tag as Version...`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can even do it from Project Explorer or Navigator. Right click on source you would like to tag -> Team -> Tag as Version.

[image]

Once you click on Tag as Version, it will pop up another window as below. Add the tag name you wish and click OK.

[image]

You can verify tag name through Right click on resource -> Team -> Show History

[image]